# How can I scale sprite sheet images to a container?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I have a container with a background image that scales to the width of a screen, up to a maximum size of 1400px. I want to take icons from a sprite sheet and scale them proportionally to how the container is scaling.

The size of the icons, as well as the placement of the icons within the container are important. At the maximum size of 1400px, everything is great. But when scaling down, I want the icons to also scale down in size and keep the correct positioning relative to the background image of the container.

Right now, the icons do not scale down with the container: https://jsfiddle.net/KakeWalk/2hduxzLe/

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid striped-background">
  <div id="blue-section">
    <div id="AAAA"></div>
    <div id="BBBB"></div>
    <div id="CCCC"></div>
    <div id="DDDD"></div>
    <div id="EEEE"></div>
    <div id="FFFF"></div>
    <div id="GGGG"></div>
    <div id="HHHH"></div>
    <div id="IIII"></div>
    <div id="JJJJ"></div>
    <div id="KKKK"></div>
    <div id="LLLL"></div>
    <div id="MMMM"></div>
    <div id="NNNN"></div>
    <div id="OOOO"></div>
    <div id="PPPP"></div>
    <div id="QQQQ"></div>
    <div id="RRRR"></div>
    <div id="SSSS"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.striped-background {
  background-image: url("https://imgur.com/7sSDRKV.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  max-width: 1400px;
  height: 520px;
  background-size: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#blue-section div {
  height: 92px;
  width: 92px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}

#AAAA {
  left: 4.5%;
  top: 15%;
  background: url("https://imgur.com/8L1Y4SS.png") 0.476190% 0.476190%;
}

#BBBB {
  left: 15.05%;
  top: 15%;
  background: url("https://imgur.com/8L1Y4SS.png") 22.8571% 0.476190%;
}

#CCCC {
  left: 36.16%;
  top: 15%;
  background: url("https://imgur.com/8L1Y4SS.png") 45.2381% 0.476190%;
}

#DDDD {
  left: 46.72%;
  top: 15%;
  background: url("https://imgur.com/8L1Y4SS.png") 67.6190% 0.476190%;
}

#EEEE {
  left: 9.77%;
  top: 65%;
  background: url("https://imgur.com/8L1Y4SS.png") 90.0000% 0.476190%;
}

#FFFF {
  left: 20.33%;
  top: 50%;
  background: url("https://imgur.com/8L1Y4SS.png") 0.476190% 22.8571%;
}

#GGGG {
  left: 20.33%;
  top: 80%;
  background: url("https://imgur.com/8L1Y4SS.png") 22.8571% 22.8571%;
}

#HHHH {
  left: 30.88%;
  top: 40%;
  background: url("https://imgur.com/8L1Y4SS.png") 45.2381% 22.8571%;
}

#IIII {
  left: 30.88%;
  top: 65%;
  background: url("https://imgur.com/8L1Y4SS.png") 67.6190% 22.8571%;
}

#JJJJ {
  left: 41.44%;
  top: 65%;
  background: url("https://imgur.com/8L1Y4SS.png") 90.0000% 22.8571%;
}

#KKKK {
  left: 57.27%;
  top: 30%;
  background: url("https://imgur.com/8L1Y4SS.png") 0.476190% 45.2381%;
}

#LLLL {
  left: 57.27%;
  top: 65%;
  background: url("https://imgur.com/8L1Y4SS.png") 22.8571% 45.2381%;
}

#MMMM {
  left: 78.38%;
  top: 40%;
  background: url("https://imgur.com/8L1Y4SS.png") 45.2381% 45.2381%;
}

#NNNN {
  left: 67.83%;
  top: 40%;
  background: url("https://imgur.com/8L1Y4SS.png") 67.6190% 45.2381%;
}

#OOOO {
  left: 73.11%;
  top: 15%;
  background: url("https://imgur.com/8L1Y4SS.png") 90.0000% 45.2381%;
}

#PPPP {
  left: 83.66%;
  top: 15%;
  background: url("https://imgur.com/8L1Y4SS.png") 0.476190% 67.6190%;
}

#QQQQ {
  left: 88.94%;
  top: 40%;
  background: url("https://imgur.com/8L1Y4SS.png") 22.8571% 67.6190%;
}

#RRRR {
  left: 83.66%;
  top: 65%;
  background: url("https://imgur.com/8L1Y4SS.png") 45.2381% 67.6190%;
}

#SSSS {
  left: 73.11%;
  top: 65%;
  background: url("https://imgur.com/8L1Y4SS.png") 67.6190% 67.6190%;
}
```

To get the background-position percentages, I used a Responsive CSS Sprite Generator that gave me this CSS:

```
/*
Responsive CSS Sprite created using: https://responsive-css.us/
*/

.AAAA, .BBBB, .CCCC, .DDDD, .EEEE, .FFFF, .GGGG, .HHHH, .IIII, .JJJJ, .KKKK, .LLLL, .MMMM, .NNNN, .OOOO, .PPPP, .QQQQ, .RRRR, .SSSS 
{display:inline-block; overflow:hidden; background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-image:url(sprite.png);}

.AAAA {width: 92px; height: 92px; background-position: 0.476190% 0.476190%; background-size: 556.522%; }
.BBBB {width: 92px; height: 92px; background-position: 22.8571% 0.476190%; background-size: 556.522%; }
.CCCC {width: 92px; height: 92px; background-position: 45.2381% 0.476190%; background-size: 556.522%; }
.DDDD {width: 92px; height: 92px; background-position: 67.6190% 0.476190%; background-size: 556.522%; }
.EEEE {width: 92px; height: 92px; background-position: 90.0000% 0.476190%; background-size: 556.522%; }
.FFFF {width: 92px; height: 92px; background-position: 0.476190% 22.8571%; background-size: 556.522%; }
.GGGG {width: 92px; height: 92px; background-position: 22.8571% 22.8571%; background-size: 556.522%; }
.HHHH {width: 92px; height: 92px; background-position: 45.2381% 22.8571%; background-size: 556.522%; }
.IIII {width: 92px; height: 92px; background-position: 67.6190% 22.8571%; background-size: 556.522%; }
.JJJJ {width: 92px; height: 92px; background-position: 90.0000% 22.8571%; background-size: 556.522%; }
.KKKK {width: 92px; height: 92px; background-position: 0.476190% 45.2381%; background-size: 556.522%; }
.LLLL {width: 92px; height: 92px; background-position: 22.8571% 45.2381%; background-size: 556.522%; }
.MMMM {width: 92px; height: 92px; background-position: 45.2381% 45.2381%; background-size: 556.522%; }
.NNNN {width: 92px; height: 92px; background-position: 67.6190% 45.2381%; background-size: 556.522%; }
.OOOO {width: 92px; height: 92px; background-position: 90.0000% 45.2381%; background-size: 556.522%; }
.PPPP {width: 92px; height: 92px; background-position: 0.476190% 67.6190%; background-size: 556.522%; }
.QQQQ {width: 92px; height: 92px; background-position: 22.8571% 67.6190%; background-size: 556.522%; }
.RRRR {width: 92px; height: 92px; background-position: 45.2381% 67.6190%; background-size: 556.522%; }
.SSSS {width: 92px; height: 92px; background-position: 67.6190% 67.6190%; background-size: 556.522%; }
```

I tried copy/pasting this code into my project and changing the classes to IDs and the other way around, but had no success. None of the many things I've tried have gotten me any closer to the goal than what I posted here: https://jsfiddle.net/KakeWalk/2hduxzLe/

Comment: If you want the icons to scale down when the browser window gets smaller, define their width and height as percentages instead of pixel values

Comment: You might wanna look into [Viewport-percentage lengths](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length)

Comment: I'm getting a little success playing with viewport lengths. It seems like the icons now move vertically after switching the left/top values from % to vw. But the icons are still staying the same size. I've tried using % or vw in place of px, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Actually that seems to have introduced a new issue, so still not really getting anywhere. I'm going to keep looking into viewport percentage lengths, but any additional help or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there, just need to specify some values in `%`.
Run the snippet below in fullscreen and resize:

```css
.striped-background {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1400px;
  padding: 37.143% 0 0;
 /* 520px is 37.143% from 1400px so we keep the aspect ratio */
  background: url("https://imgur.com/7sSDRKV.png") no-repeat 0 0 / cover;
}

#blue-section div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 6.6%; /* 92px is 6.6% from 1400px */
  padding: 6.6% 0 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: url("https://imgur.com/8L1Y4SS.png");
  background-size: 556.522%; 
  /* the width of your sprite is 512px where 460px for 5 symbols (92px each)
  and the rest of the space is for unnecessary extra space. 
  So if there was no extra space, background-size would be 500% (100% for 5 symbols)
  but we have to multiply this number to 512/460 what gives us 556.522%  */
}

#AAAA {
  left: 4.5%;
  top: 15%;
  background-position: 0.476190% 0.476190%;
}

#BBBB {
  left: 15.05%;
  top: 15%;
  background-position: 22.8571% 0.476190%;
}

#CCCC {
  left: 36.16%;
  top: 15%;
  background-position: 45.2381% 0.476190%;
}

#DDDD {
  left: 46.72%;
  top: 15%;
  background-position: 67.6190% 0.476190%;
}

#EEEE {
  left: 9.77%;
  top: 65%;
  background-position: 90.0000% 0.476190%;
}

#FFFF {
  left: 20.33%;
  top: 50%;
  background-position: 0.476190% 22.8571%;
}

#GGGG {
  left: 20.33%;
  top: 80%;
  background-position: 22.8571% 22.8571%;
}

#HHHH {
  left: 30.88%;
  top: 40%;
  background-position: 45.2381% 22.8571%;
}

#IIII {
  left: 30.88%;
  top: 65%;
  background-position: 67.6190% 22.8571%;
}

#JJJJ {
  left: 41.44%;
  top: 65%;
  background-position: 90.0000% 22.8571%;
}

#KKKK {
  left: 57.27%;
  top: 30%;
  background-position: 0.476190% 45.2381%;
}

#LLLL {
  left: 57.27%;
  top: 65%;
  background-position: 22.8571% 45.2381%;
}

#MMMM {
  left: 78.38%;
  top: 40%;
  background-position: 45.2381% 45.2381%;
}

#NNNN {
  left: 67.83%;
  top: 40%;
  background-position: 67.6190% 45.2381%;
}

#OOOO {
  left: 73.11%;
  top: 15%;
  background-position: 90.0000% 45.2381%;
}

#PPPP {
  left: 83.66%;
  top: 15%;
  background-position: 0.476190% 67.6190%;
}

#QQQQ {
  left: 88.94%;
  top: 40%;
  background-position: 22.8571% 67.6190%;
}

#RRRR {
  left: 83.66%;
  top: 65%;
  background-position: 45.2381% 67.6190%;
}

#SSSS {
  left: 73.11%;
  top: 65%;
  background-position: 67.6190% 67.6190%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid striped-background">
  <div id="blue-section">
    <div id="AAAA"></div>
    <div id="BBBB"></div>
    <div id="CCCC"></div>
    <div id="DDDD"></div>
    <div id="EEEE"></div>
    <div id="FFFF"></div>
    <div id="GGGG"></div>
    <div id="HHHH"></div>
    <div id="IIII"></div>
    <div id="JJJJ"></div>
    <div id="KKKK"></div>
    <div id="LLLL"></div>
    <div id="MMMM"></div>
    <div id="NNNN"></div>
    <div id="OOOO"></div>
    <div id="PPPP"></div>
    <div id="QQQQ"></div>
    <div id="RRRR"></div>
    <div id="SSSS"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This helps so much! I hope you don't mind if I ask a couple of questions so I can fully understand what's going on. How do I keep the max height of the image to be no larger than it's original size of 520px? And how did you come up with those percentages I was missing?

Comment: @BrianHead, thank you, I've updated my answer. Please see my comments in CSS.