# How can I position an image sprite sheet like browser games React js

Tags: css, reactjs

I build a game in react js. This game has the same mechanics as Travian Game. I have some problem from frontend development.

There is an background image and it has specific area for building.

[image: two muppets]

If build a building in red area
[image: two muppets]

After finish building looks like this.
[image: two muppets]

How can I make it in React JS Web?
I tried SVG Path but I can not place image exact position in different screen resolutions.
Also I tried Image Mapper but I cannot place image exact position in different screen resolutions.

All buildable areas must be clickable and responsible.

Comment: Why not use percentages to declare the houses' location?

Comment: did you mean like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/53271867/9264686

Comment: Yes, it's the simplest solution to what you're describing, assuming the background image always has the same dimensions

Comment: The background image needs to be full screen and should not be scrolled. Except for the phone portrait. Then I need to fix the height at 400

Comment: Then percent form is the way to go